# Missing semicolon in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

this is my code

```
    CREATE  PROCEDURE busqueda
(
nombreq VARCHAR(200),
grupo VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
SELECT nombre = nombreq FROM tabla1
END
```

In the `END` there's this error

> syntax error: missing semicolon

Adding a semicolon at the end doesn't work

Comment: semicolon in missing at end of SELECT query 
"SELECT nombre = nombreq FROM tabla1;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is full correct code:

```
    delimiter $$
    CREATE  PROCEDURE busqueda
    (
    nombreq VARCHAR(200),
    grupo VARCHAR(200)
    )
    BEGIN
    SELECT nombre = nombreq FROM tabla1;
    END
    $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the code that you really want.  My best guess would be:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE busqueda (
    OUT out_nombre VARCHAR(200),
    IN in_grupo VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT in_nombre := t1.nombreq
    FROM tabla1 t1
    WHERE t1.grupo = in_grupo;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Notes:

- Note the naming convention for the input parameters.  This makes it much easier to avoid naming conflicts in queries in the stored procedure.
- Your code is assigning an arbitrary `nombreq` to the parameter.  I added a `WHERE` clause.
- I imagine -- because you are setting the value -- that you want the value changed for the input parameter.
- In a `SELECT`, assignment uses `:=`, not `=` (or `into`).